# How to mark loop index?

Tags: java, loops

Hi I am trying to mark a position that already been visited

This string

```
String s = "123+4+3233"
```

and multiple index.

So I will loop it gotta be ***inner loop***

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123+4+3233";
        String n = "";
        int count = 0;
        List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) > 0){
                for(int k = i; k < s.length(); k++){
                    if(s.charAt(k) == '+'){
                        break;
                    }
                    if(s.charAt(k) != '+'){
                        n += s.charAt(k);
                    }
                }
                if(!(n.isEmpty())){
                    lists.add(n);
                    n = "";
                }
                if(s.charAt(i) == '+'){count++; }
            }
       }
        System.out.println(lists);
    }
```

and this result would come out Since I don't know how to mark the place that already visited.
***CANNOT USE SPLIT***

```
[123, 23, 3, 4, 3233, 233, 33, 3]
```

I just want

***EXPECTED RESULT***

```
[123, 4, 3233]
```

Comment: would it be ok to use regexp ?

Comment: no bro can not use it casue it's part of compiler

Comment: Why can't you use split()? If you just want [123, 4, 3233] then do ``s.split("+");``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to mark the place that visited, simply advance the `i` index:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "123+4+3233";
    String n = "";
    int count = 0;
    List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) > 0){
            int k = i;
            for(; k < s.length(); k++){
                if(s.charAt(k) == '+'){
                    break;
                }
                if(s.charAt(k) != '+'){
                    n += s.charAt(k);
                }
            }
            if(!(n.isEmpty())){
                lists.add(n);
                n = "";
            }
            if(s.charAt(i) == '+'){count++; }

            if(k > i)i = k - 1; //advance i to the right position
        }
   }
    System.out.println(lists);
}
```

output:

```
[123, 4, 3233]
```

Comment: hey bro I have encounter a few problems if there are more loops in that main loop. such as if the string doesn't stop when it reach to the end and it keeps subtracting.

Comment: @realNameDoesn'tExist Not really get you, you mean when it reachs to the end, restart the for loop to process another new string? or say you have more than one string to process?  if that's what you mean, you could just put all the code in the `main` into another static method, for example, `process(String str)`, then rewrite `main` to ` for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){process(stringArray[i]);}`.

Comment: sorry about above comment. It's work fines now can you explain to me why it's  if(k>i) { i = k-1; }

Comment: Sure, think about when inner for loop will stop every time? it must be either a `+` char or the end of the string is met ,right ? So for the first situation where a `+` char is met,  that means you find a number, for example, in this string "123+4+3233", when you meet the first `+` char at the index of 3, you save the first number `123` in your lists, after this you start to find next number, then must start from index of 3 (k == 3 at this time ) because you are counting `+` at the time,

Comment: but why i = k - 1,  it's because in outer for loop you do i++, it kind of balance out to let i start from k in next loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating this one a bit. Here's how I would solve it:

```
String s = 123+4+3233;
ArrayList<String> nums = new ArrayList<>();

int lastPlus = 0; // Keeping track of the last index at which there was a "+"

for (int j = 0 j < s.length(); j++) {
    if (s.charAt(j).equals("+")) {
        nums.add(s.substring(lastPlus, j));
        lastPlus = j + 1; //The "+1" skips over the plus for the next substring()
    }

    // This last 'if' statement is for adding that last bit of numbers
    if (j == s.length() - 1 && !(s.charAt(j).equals("+"))) { 
        nums.add(lastPlus);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done in a shorter way:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    String s = "123+4+3233";
    List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
        String temp = "";
        while(i<s.length() && s.charAt(i) != '+'){
            temp+= s.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
        lists.add(temp);
    }
    System.out.println(lists);
}
```